# Create New Windows Azure Hosted Service from a Worker Role

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-worker-roles, azure-role-environment

What is the best way to create a new Windows Azure Hosted service from a running role using a package and configuration that I have stored in blob storage?

I am guessing that I could use a Service Management REST API Create Deployment request, however running a cmdlet from my worker role might be better. Any thoughts? If the cmdlet route is better, bonus points if you can point me in the right direction on how to run them from a worker role.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what is 'best' here because it depends on what you are trying to do.  If you just need to create a hosted service programmatically it would be about the same to create a REST client, upload a cert, and just do it versus using the cmdlets or anything else.

As the creator of the cmdlets, they have a special place in my heart, but I would probably stick to using those for IT admin tasks.  They rock for cmd line automation.

That being said, it is not terribly hard to roll your own client, but I typically recommend that you download the [Service Managements contracts from csmanage](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Windows-Azure-CSManage-e3f1882c).  That way, you have a simple wrapper around this to get going.  While it does use WCF, it is not too onerous.